# SQL Server EXECUTE AS misbehavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, impersonation, execute-as

I have a user which I gave grant access to credential using:

```sql
GRANT ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL TO userA
```

When I log in with that user, the following returns me data

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.credentials
```

I can see that I have the permission on the SERVER level. This can be verified by doing

```sql
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'SERVER')
```

Using another user, say userB, I gave impersonation to userA by doing

```sql
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::userA TO userB
```

In a stored procedure, while being logged as userB, I switch the context to userA

```sql
EXECUTE AS user = 'userA'
SELECT user_name() AS ContextUserName
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'SERVER')
SELECT * FROM sys.credentials
```

`SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'SERVER')` doesn't return me ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL permission.
`SELECT * FROM sys.credentials` doesn't return me any values.
`SELECT user_name()` returns me userA however.

Is there anything I've missed here? Why can't I behave like userA and get data from sys.credentials?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is probably, that `EXECUTE AS` is only granting UserB the permissions of UserA on the database you are executing it, but not the permissions given on the server. 
That's why `SELECT user_name()` is showing UserA, but `SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'SERVER')` is not showing the permissions of UserA, but the permissions of UserB.

**Microsoft Docs:**

[EXECUTE AS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
"The scope of impersonation is restricted to the current database. A context switch to a database user does not inherit the server-level permissions of that user."

[sys.fn_my_permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
"`SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');` returns a list of the effective permissions of the caller on the **server**."

Comment: Thank you! I guess last night coding does have its caveats.

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias mentioned, I was `Executing AS` the USER and not LOGIN. I had to `GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::` for this to work.

Comment: db user impersonation would also work if the db was trusted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property